# SSIS Script Task conflicting assembly references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a c# script task and I am getting the warning below.  I have NewtonSoft.json v12 referenced but this is saying I am also referencing v13.  I cannot figure out where I am referencing v13 so I can remove the reference.  I even tried starting from scratch with a new project and a new script task, and the warning showed up again.  The script actually runs fine when I run it locally, even with the warning, but fails on the server when it gets to the code that uses newtonsoft.  Any guidance on how to get rid of this warning would be greatly appreciated.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 and deploying to SQL Server 2017.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning 

Found conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could not be resolved.

There was a conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" 
and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed".
"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" was chosen because it was primary 
and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" was not.

References which depend on "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" 
[C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_12.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll].
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_12.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_12.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL

References which depend on "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" [].
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll

Project file item includes which caused reference 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll".

Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91  ST_0a72ca207021453086f7f4306b6593b0 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2203
```

Comment: I just tried creating a new project with fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 on a brand new computer and got the same warning

Comment: It looks like there's 2-3 different version of newtonsoft on your machine. v12 is in the global assembly cache (GAC). DTS wants v13 via Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll Knowing nothing of package management, I'd get a copy of v13 of Newtonsoft and stuff that into the GAC (approximately `gacutil -if NewtonSoftV13.dll`)  and update your package references to V13

Comment: I ended up upgrading to Windows Server 2022 and everything started working again.